# Juxtapose Two Columns Based On Matching Reference Columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Disclaimer: My "due diligence search" prior to posting was fruitless, mostly because I'm not sure how to word this problem. Please redirect me if this is an old question.

I have two sheets, each with a set of group names and their associated scores. The first sheet contains a full list of (unique) group names with scores, and the second sheet contains a subset of those same group names with different scores. I'd like to make a third sheet with one column of all group names, and their respective scores in the next two columns. Please see the image below

[image: Please reference this image for a basic example]

Ideally, I'd like to use Google Sheets, but I think Excel may be better suited for this...which I can deal with. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Looks like you can use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formulae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy in Sheets if prepared to insert a new ColumnE:

```
=query({A1:C99;D1:F99},"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) where Col1 is not NULL group by Col1")
```

(Adjust column labels to suit.)

Comment: Very interesting...I'm sorry to say I've never used the Query function, but it seems very useful!  

That said, are you suggesting that I insert a new column to the left of the current E (therefore, shifting it over to F) and making the new column equal to this equation? If that's the case...I get a circular dependency error...  

I will continue to read up on how to use Query

Comment: It looks like a change of Settings now allows circular referencing...but now I'm getting errors that Array Literals are missing values...